# Outlook web addin(owa) cookie deletion problem

Tags: cookies, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I add value to my cookie in Outlook web addin but my different controller cookie object is null
I've had the same problem since yesterday but there was no such problem before how can i solve this problem

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your ASP.net mvc controller configuration. 

Please refer to this doc to understand the situation better : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs

Furthermore, in order to understand it better : 1. Is it happening for all browsers ? 2. Is the issue consistent ? 3. Do you see any console errors ? 4. Did you recently update/change anything which might trigger the behavior ?

Comment: no console errors, I just changed the manifest.xml file, There are cookies in the browser but I cannot access from the backend

Comment: What changes did you introduce to the manifext.xml file ?
Can you try with the older manifest file to see if it reproduces ?

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't

Comment: https: // localhost: 44365 / I can access the cookie when I enter but https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/ I cannot access the cookie from this link

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue from our side. 
The reason can range from a wide variety of options like mal-configuration of the controller, browser policy changes etc. 
Please let us know if any API fails for you, we can help with that.